# Ubuntu equivalent to bugs.debian.org/<package>?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

In Debian, I can use the above URL to quickly see the open bugs for a package.  In Ubuntu, it seems I have to go to launchpad, and click, click, click... which is .

Is there a quick way to see all the bugs of a package in Ubuntu?  One which doesn't require clicking through hell and back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a link called "Bug Reports" at the package information page of every [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). You can also try to open `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/[PACKAGE NAME]/+bugs` directly.

Take `apache2` in Ubuntu 9.10 as an example: http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/apache2 leads to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bugs

Comment: The packages link, while still not as direct as Debian's (well, packages.ubuntu.com looks like it's the same code as p.d.o), is better than "clicking through hell and back", so thanks.